# How can I make the dropdown button responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, responsive

I need help with the responsiveness of the two drop-down buttons, when it opens the button is above the text and I want it to be like that, but I don't know how to make it responsive, it is done via the command (position: absolute;) to be above the text, the problem is that when when the button is opened, the text in that button will not be reduced when it is opened, it always remains the same and does not look nice,

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 1300px;
}

.dropdown {
    border: #fff solid 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    background-color: #86c232;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content_brand {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 1280px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.dropdown_container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.dropdown-content_brand a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content_brand {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

.btn {
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 25%;
}

.btn_show_brand {
    background-color: #86c232;
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 96.5%;
    float: left;
}
</style>



<div class="dropdown_container">

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Brand</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content_brand">
            <div class="btn_show"> <button class="btn_show_brand active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button> </div>
            <div class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('sram')">SRAM</div>
            <div class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('shimano')">SHIMANO</div>
            <div class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('rockshox')">ROCKSHOX</div>
            <div class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('magura')">MAGURA</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add more clarity on what you are trying to achieve. Especially here `the text in that button will not be reduced when it is opened, it always remains the same and does not look nice`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) can help you, for exemple:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown_container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content_brand {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```